# Merge dictionary and tab

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge

I need help in order to merge dictionary and tab.

Here is the `dic`:

```py
dic = {
    267970: [
        ('species', 'Bean yellow disorder virus'),
        ('genus', 'Crinivirus'),
        ('family', 'Closteroviridae'),
        ('sub_family','Closyerovirinae'),
        ('no_rank', 'ssRNA positive-strand viruses, no DNA stage'), 
        ('no_rank', 'ssRNA viruses'),
        ('superkingdom', 'Viruses')
    ],
    190063: [
        ('species', 'Fowl aviadenovirus C'),
        ('genus', 'Aviadenovirus'),
        ('family', 'Adenoviridae'),
        ('no_rank', 'dsDNA viruses, no RNA stage'),
        ('superkingdom', 'Viruses')
    ]
}
```

As you can see, in the `dic` there can be `> 1 no_rank` information, so I guess we should first rename the `no_rank` in `dic` as by adding a number next to it:

```py
dic = {
    267970: [
        ('species', 'Bean yellow disorder virus'),
        ('genus', 'Crinivirus'),
        ('family', 'Closteroviridae'),
        ('sub_family','Closyerovirinae'),
        ('no_rank1', 'ssRNA positive-strand viruses, no DNA stage'), 
        ('no_rank2', 'ssRNA viruses'),
        ('superkingdom', 'Viruses')
    ],
    190063: [
        ('species', 'Fowl aviadenovirus C'),
        ('genus', 'Aviadenovirus'),
        ('family', 'Adenoviridae'),
        ('no_rank1', 'dsDNA viruses, no RNA stage'),
        ('superkingdom', 'Viruses')
    ]
}
```

And I have a `tab1` file such as:

```
Species_names ID
Species1      267970
Species2      190063
```

And I would like to add the `dic` to a new tab by merging the `dic` and `tab1` to get:

```
Species_names ID     species                    genus         family          sub_family      no_rank1                                    no_rank2      super_kingdom
Species1      267970 Bean yellow disorder virus Crinivirus    Closteroviridae Closterovirinae ssRNA positive-strand viruses, no DNA stage ssRNA viruses Viruses
Species2      190063 Fowl aviadenovirus C       Aviadenovirus Adenoviridae    NA              dsDNA viruses, no RNA stage                 NA            Viruses
```

Does anyone have an idea?

For the last part I tried:

```py
tab1.merge(
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index'),
    left_on='ID',
    right_index=True
)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want the field renaming to be handled for you automatically, for whatever many repetitions of however many fields, or is the `dic` with the renamed fields supposed to be the input?

Comment: Yes I want the field renaming to be handled for you automatically, for whatever many repetitions of however many field

Comment: For the last part (the merge), it works if instead of `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient='index')` you do `pd.DataFrame({k: dict(v) for k, v in dic.items()}).T` (with the `dic` with renamed fields). But for the field renaming, I don't know if there is a Pandas function to do that (I feel there _should_ be though). The alternative is to go through the data yourself, taking note of the fields that need renaming to then actually rename them in a second pass...

Comment: Ok I see, thank you anyway for your answer it helped a lot.